Optimizing Wireless Communication for High Data Rate and Low Latency
I am working on a project to convert a wired system to wireless. The setup consists of a master device that transmits a data packet of 30 bytes to 2000 devices. The maximum distance between the master and slaves is 7 meters.
The main challenges are achieving a data rate of 2 Mbps in real life and maintaining low latency. The packets need to be sent at a frequency of 5 kHz, which translates to a duty cycle of 200 µs.
I have experimented with several technologies, including LoRa (which couldn't handle the required data rate) and ESP-NOW. ESP-NOW performed better, as I managed to program the master to transmit every 200 µs. However, I struggled to receive data at the same interval on the receiver side, achieving a minimum duty cycle of 880 µs.
Could anyone suggest alternative technologies or provide guidance on optimizing my setup using ESP-NOW to meet these requirements?
Thank you!

I believe that ad-hoc WiFi would work well, as long as the slave nodes are configured with a fixed IP and listen-only. A UDP broadcast will then easily keep up with the packet rate. The hardware is also dirt cheap because an ESP with WiFi and even a lousy receive antenna will work great over such small distance. Since the nodes will never transmit, the high number of nodes is immaterial.
It is also possible for a few nodes to associate with the master and transmit - but just very few. So it is possible to e.g. get periodic status readbacks from all the nodes. The nodes would need to either turn transmitter on and associate on a fixed schedule, or at sufficiently long randomly generated intervals. The idea is to have never more than say 10-20 nodes with transmitter enabled at the same time.

Thanks for your answer. If I used ad-hoc WiFi will I be able to transmit directly to the 2000 devices?

@Sondos ad-hoc WiFi without association is pure broadcast. It doesn't matter how many devices are listening - the master doesn't know how many there are. All the listening devices are listen-only, and they all receive the ethernet packets. It's then up to each device to figure out if it's a packet for it or not. Alternatively, if the list of all listener MACs is loaded into the master in the factory or during commissioning, the master can send directed messages using the listener MAC. That way other listeners will reject the packet.

Ah okay I will try it and tell you thank you very much for your support.

In your project to convert a wired system to wireless, there are particularly with the requirements of 5 kHz frequency (200 µs duty cycle), high data rate (2 Mbps), and low latency communication for 2000 devices within a 7-meter range.
Alternativly, you can experiment with Wi-Fi 6 (802.11ax). As I know, Wi-Fi 6 supports very high data rates (up to 9.6 Gbps) and improves on previous standards with OFDMA and MU-MIMO, which can help manage many devices more effectively. Also, Wi-Fi 6 is designed for low-latency applications, and OFDMA allows multiple devices to be served simultaneously by dividing the bandwidth more efficiently. It probably could potentially achieve your 200 µs duty cycle requirement.

thanks for your answer. will WIFI6 support sending to the 2000 devices directly or will I need intermediate devices. Because I need all the devices to be as synchronized as possible with the minimum delay between them.
